# How can a script distinguish Docker Toolbox and Docker for Windows?

Tags: docker, scripting, docker-for-windows, docker-toolbox, docker-desktop

On my current team, we're still transitioning from **Docker Toolbox** to **Docker Desktop for Windows**. A lot of our scripts still assume that you're running Docker Toolbox on VirtualBox (like how to mount drives, how slashes or drive names work for those mounts).

Is there a reliable way to tell, from inside a script, whether `docker` is coming from Docker Toolbox or Docker Desktop for Windows?

Comment: Are you trying to detect this on the windows host? so from the script where you are running the `docker` command from?

Comment: Windows host; docker is expected to be on the PATH.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Toolbox works via `docker-machine`. The way the `docker` client is directed to the virtual machine is via a number of environment variables which you can see by running `docker-machine env default`

```
SET DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
SET DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.99.100:2376
SET DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/user/.docker/machine/machines/default
SET DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME=default
REM Run this command to configure your shell: 
REM     @FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('docker-machine env --shell cmd default') DO @%i
```

Docker for Mac connects directly to the `/var/run/docker.sock` socket which is mapped into the Docker VM so this is easy to detect by the lack of environment variables.

I believe Docker for Windows uses a named pipe in the same way (`//./pipe/docker_engine`) so you should also be able to tell by the lack of `DOCKER_HOST` in the environment.

If Docker for Windows does still use the environment, there will be differences between the Toolbox and Docker for Windows variables. `DOCKER_HOST` would be on a different range. `DOCKER_CERT_PATH` won't include `machine` etc.

Comment: Lots of info, thank you. Will report back what I find.

Answer (score 4):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

dockerIsToolBox() {
  if [ "${DOCKER_TOOLBOX_INSTALL_PATH}" ];then
    echo true
  else
    echo false
  fi
}
```