# How to distinguish between Docker Toolbox and Docker for Mac/Windows?

Tags: docker, docker-machine, boot2docker, docker-toolbox

Is it possible to distinguish whether a user is using Docker Toolbox or Docker for Mac/Windows?

I've already seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43242218/how-can-a-script-distinguish-docker-toolbox-and-docker-for-windows).

In order to do some tests, now I have both Docker for Mac and Docker Toolbox installed and running. I can run Docker for Mac simply by running:

`docker`

and Docker Toolbox by running:

`DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME=default DOCKER_CERT_PATH=$HOME/.docker/machine/machines/default DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1 DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.99.100:2376 docker`.

As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43242218/how-can-a-script-distinguish-docker-toolbox-and-docker-for-windows). I tried checking `DOCKER_TOOLBOX_INSTALL_PATH` env var, but in my case is empty. Then I thought that I could check whether the scheme of `DOCKER_HOST` is `tcp` and consider it to be Docker Toolbox, but then I realized that even with Docker for Mac is possible to have `tcp` scheme for `DOCKER_HOST`.

I then ran `docker system info` for both Docker for Mac and Docker Toolbox. I noticed that in the first case there's:

`Operating System: Docker for Mac`

while in the second case:

`Operating System: Boot2Docker 18.09.4 (TCL 8.2.1)`

Is it safe then to check whether `OperatingSystem` contains case-insensitive the string `boot2docker` for both Mac and Windows?

Comment: Why does it matter?  Also consider the (ill-advised) possibility of a remote `$DOCKER_HOST` and more complex setups like a Docker container using the host's Docker socket, and environments like Kubernetes where interacting directly with Docker is generally discouraged.

Comment: Because I'm working on an application that currently doesn't support Docker Toolbox, so I want to perform a check upfront instead of raising some unexpected errors that give no clue about the incompatibility with Docker Toolbox.